# Replacing part of a file name in a directory using python

Tags: python

I am trying to rename a set of files in a directory using python. The files are currently labelled with a Pool number, AR number and S number (e.g. Pool1_AR001_S13__fw_paired.fastq.gz.) Each file refers to a specific plant sequence name. I would like to rename these files by removing the 'Pool_AR_S' and replacing it with the sequence name e.g. 'Lbienne_dor5_GS1', while leaving the suffix (e.g. fw_paired.fastq.gz, rv_unpaired.fastq.gz), I am trying to read the files into a dictionary, but I am stuck as to what to do next. I have a .txt file containing the necessary information in the following format:

```
Pool1_AR010_S17 - Lbienne_lla10_GS2
Pool1_AR011_S18 - Lbienne_lla10_GS3
Pool1_AR020_S19 - Lcampanulatum_borau4_T_GS1
```

The code I have so far is:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
import csv
import os

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-w", "--wanted", dest="w")
parser.add_option("-t","--trimmed", dest="t")
parser.add_option("-d", "--directory", dest="working_dir", default="./")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

wanted_file = options.w
trimmomatic_output = options.t

#Read the wanted file and create a dictionary of index vs species identity

with open(wanted_file, 'rb') as species_sequence:
    species_list = list(csv.DictReader(species_sequence, delimiter='-'))
    print species_list


#Rename the Trimmomatic Output files according to the dictionary


for trimmed_sequence in os.listdir(trimmomatic_output):
os.rename(os.path.join(trimmomatic_output, trimmed_sequence),
          os.path.join(trimmomatic_output, trimmed_sequence.replace(species_list[0], species_list[1]))
```

Please can you help me to replace half of the . I'm very new to python and to stack overflow, so I am sorry if this question has been asked before or if I have asked this in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

First job is to get rid of all those modules. They may be nice, but for a job like yours they are very unlikely to make things easier.

Create a .py file in the directory where those .gz files reside.

```
import os
files = os.listdir() #files is of list type
#'txt_file' is the path of your .txt file containing those conversions
dic=parse_txt(txt_file) #omitted the body of parse_txt() func.Should return a dictionary by parsing that .txt file
for f in files:
    pre,suf=f.split('__') #"Pool1_AR001_S13__(1)fw_paired.fastq.gz"
                          #(1)=assuming prefix and suffix are divided by double underscore
    pre = dic[pre] 
    os.rename(f,pre+'__'+suf)
```

If you need help with parse_txt() function, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I tested with Python 2. Its fine if you use your own logic instead of the get_mappings function. Refer comments in code for explanation.

```
    import os

    def get_mappings():
        mappings_dict = {}
        with(open('wanted_file.txt', 'r')) as f:
            for line in f:
                # if you have Pool1_AR010_S17 - Lbienne_lla10_GS2
                # it becomes a list i.e ['Pool1_AR010_S17 ', ' Lbienne_lla10_GS2']
                #note that there may be spaces before/after the names as shown above
                text = line.split('-')
                #trim is used to remove spaces in the names
                mappings_dict[text[0].strip()] = text[1].strip()

        return mappings_dict

    #PROGRAM EXECUTION STARTS FROM HERE
    #assuming all files are in the current directory
    # if not replace the dot(.) with the path of the directory where you have the files
    files = os.listdir('.')
    wanted_names_dict = get_mappings()
    for filename in files:
        try:
            #prefix='Pool1_AR010_S17', suffix='fw_paired.fastq.gz'
            prefix, suffix = filename.split('__')
            new_filename = wanted_names_dict[prefix] + '__' + suffix
            os.rename(filename, new_filename)
            print 'renamed', filename, 'to', new_filename
        except:
            print 'No new name defined for file:' + filename
```